# How can I run a SELECT and combine multiple as additional columns in the main row?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables set up. The first table contains a listing of apartments, and the second table contains a listing of photos, each photo containing a reference to an apartment listing id.

What I'd like to do is pull down all apartments listings and combine the first two photos associated with each listing into a single row.

**To keep things simple, lets say the rows in the `apartment` table are:**

```
post_id,<br>
title,<br>
description
```

**And the rows in the `photos` table are:**

```
photo_id,<br>
post_id,<br>
path
```

**The result I'd like when performing a `SELECT * FROM apartments` is:**

```
post_id, <br>title,<br> description,<br> path1,<br> path2
```

Where `path1` and `path2` are the first and second photos in the photos table who's `post_id` reference the `post_id` of the current row being retrieved.

I've tried all sorts of joins but can't quite seem to find one that fits what I'm trying to do. Anyone know how I could get this done?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make 2 subqueries on the photo table that pick the first photo and the first photo different from the just selected first photo.

<strike>Somthing like this:</strike>

```
SELECT 
a.*, 
(SELECT path FROM photo p1 WHERE p1.post_id = a.post_id LIMIT 0, 1) AS path1,
(SELECT path FROM photo p2 WHERE p2.post_id = a.post_id AND p2.path != a.path1 LIMIT 0, 1) AS path2
FROM apartment a
```

I have no mysql here to test it, so the query might need some tuning, but it gives the general idea.

Edit: Same idea, alternative approach (using limit to take the second record):

```
SELECT 
a.*, 
(SELECT path FROM photo p1 WHERE p1.post_id = a.post_id ORDER BY p1.path LIMIT 0, 1) AS path1,
(SELECT path FROM photo p2 WHERE p2.post_id = a.post_id ORDER BY p2.path LIMIT 1, 1) AS path2
FROM apartment a
```

Comment: It would be `LIMIT 0,1` and `LIMIT 1,1`

Comment: @ypercube that's true, MySQL still doesn't cease to confuse me at times. :) updated my answer.

Comment: And 1st solution may not even work. You can't reference to another column (`path1`) in the SELECT list, I think.

Comment: worked like a charm, thanks! I also didn't know you could do something like: SELECT a.* ... this one's going to be very useful in the future :)

Comment: @ypercube yeah I was thinking the same thing and therefore wrote the second query which is also easier to understand. I left the first query for reference. updated my answer.

Comment: @user979794 `SELECT a.*` is equal to `SELECT *` but in the former you specify that the `*` only refers to the table `a`, in this case `apartment`. It becomes more relevant when you start using multiple tables, otherwise `*` means everything from every table. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
SELECT 
    a.*, 
    MIN(IF(t.num = 1, t.path, NULL)) path1, 
    MIN(IF(t.num = 2, t.path, NULL)) path2 
FROM 
    apartments a
LEFT JOIN 
    (SELECT p1.*, COUNT(*) num 
     FROM posts p1
     LEFT JOIN posts p2 ON p2.post_id = p1.post_id
                        AND p2.photo_id <= p1.photo_id
     GROUP BY p1.post_id, p1.photo_id
     HAVING COUNT(*) < 3) t ON a.post_id = t.post_id
GROUP BY 
    a.post_id, a.title, a.description;
```

The subqueries based on rank position of photo_id, the main query checks `num` field to select one of them - first or second photo.

Comment: This one worked, but it returned only results that had at least two photos. I tried one of other solutions listed and things are looking pretty good. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Change JOIN with LEFT JOIN. I modified the answer.